# Conditional probability with exponential distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

Suppose that $X \sim \mathcal{E}(1.3)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{E}(1.7)$ are two exponential random variables and define $U := \min\{X, Y\}$.

How do I calculate following values?

- $\mathbb{P}[U > 0.32 \mid X > 0.19]$
- $\mathbb{P}[U > 0.19 \mid X > 0.32]$

Comment: Don't forget to mention that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Without this you cannot answer this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

The first one is
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}[U > 0.32\mid X > 0.19]
 &= \mathbb{P}[\min\{X,Y\} > 0.32\mid X > 0.19] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[X > 0.32, Y > 0.32\mid X > 0.19]
\end{split}
$$

Now use independence and compute. Similarly the second one...

Comment: Can you please do the math?
I don't know how to compute it. Thank You

Comment: @GinoPino This is generally not a place where people do your work for you, but I am happy to guide you instead. What does $\mathbb{P}[A\mid B]$ mean? Can you use the definition to compute $\mathbb{P}[X>0.32 \mid X > 0.19]$?

Comment: Alright: P[ X>0.32 ∣ X>0.19 ] = P[ X>0.32 ∩ X>0.19 ] / P[ X>0.19 ] = P[ X>0.32 ] / P[ X>0.19 ] = exp(-0.32*1.3) / exp(-0.19*1.3)

Comment: @GinoPino Fantastic. Now if $X > 0.32$ then $X > 0.19$, so can you simplify the numerator? Then compute them both since you know the distribution of $X$.

Comment: @GinoPino Further, since $X,Y$ are independent, the events of $Y$ do not influence the events of $X$ and vice versa. So $\mathbb{P}[X>a,Y>b\mid X>c] = \mathbb{P}[Y > b] \cdot \mathbb{P}[X>a \mid X>c]$, and the rest is arithmetic. Can you now finish it?

Comment: So P[Y>b]⋅P[X>a∣X>c] = P[ Y>b ] * P[ X > a-c ] ?

Comment: @GinoPino since $X$ is exponential, yes